# An expression tree may not contain an 'is' pattern-matching operator

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to use `Automapper` to map these properties

```
public class SourceClass
{
    public object emailNotification { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationClass
{
    public int emailNotificationId { get; set; }
    public string emailNotificationLookupName { get; set; }
}
```

When I debug it, `emailNotification` = `ValueKind = Object : "{ "id": 3, "lookupName": "Send Email Notification" }"`.

The expected outcome is

- emailNotificationId = 3
- emailNotificationLookupName = "Send Email Notification"

This is my current code for mapping, but I have this compilation errror: `An expression tree may not contain an 'is' pattern-matching operator.` in `src.emailNotification is JObject jObject`

```
public class SourceProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public SourceProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()     
            .ForMember(dest => dest.emailNotificationId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                src.emailNotification != null && src.emailNotification is JObject jObject ? jObject["id"].Value<int>() : 0))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.emailNotificationLookupName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                src.emailNotification != null && src.emailNotification is JObject jObject ? jObject["lookupName"].Value<string>() : null))
        ;
                        
    }
}
```

After trying out both solutions from Yong Shun, I could compile without error but I still could not get the value mapped.

[image]

[image]

New screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `as` operator for the type-casting to replace the `is` in order to resolve the issue:

```cs
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()     
    .ForMember(dest => dest.emailNotificationId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
        src.emailNotification != null ? JObject.FromObject(src.emailNotification)["id"].Value<int>() : 0))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.emailNotificationLookupName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
        src.emailNotification != null ? JObject.FromObject(src.emailNotification)["lookupName"].Value<string>() : null))
```

Since the logic to validate the `emailNotification` is not `null` and type-casting to `JObject` duplicate in multiple places, you may consider migrating the logic in the `AfterMap` action:

```cs
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()     
    .AfterMap((src, dest, context) =>
    {
        if (src.emailNotification != null)
        {
            JObject jObject = JObject.FromObject(src.emailNotification);
            dest.emailNotificationId = jObject["id"].Value<int>();
            dest.emailNotificationLookupName = jObject["lookupName"].Value<string>();
        }
    });
```

---

**Updated**

Note that the `emailNotification` show the value `ValueKind = Object` which is the [`JsonElement` from *System.Text.Json*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=net-7.0). Thus you need to take additional step in order to converting to `JObject`.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(src.emailNotification.ToString());
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CJj2R2)

Comment: After trying out both solutions from Yong Shun, I could compile without error but I still could not get the value mapped. I added 2 screenshot in my original post

Comment: Hi, from your screenshot, the `emailNotification` is object value. I think you can't cast as `JObject`, instead you should convert object to JObject via `JObject.FromObject(src.emailNotification)`. I will update my answer after 30 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the first solution. After mapping, both properties are still empty. For the second solution, during mapping, it has the error `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')'`

Comment: Ok, for Solution 2, when you debug `jObject`, what is the value? Does the `jObject` contains the `id` and `lookupName` properties? With this [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CJj2R2), both solutions work with `emailNotification` is an anonymous object, wondering whether it is the correct value as you stated? Otherwise you need to do extra handling for property when it is not existed via `?.` null conditional operator.

Comment: I just added new screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255137/discussion-between-yong-shun-and-steve).

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/) about *Expression Trees* that you might find interesting. It says that you cannot use the
*pattern matching is operator* inside one of these. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60613492/8743364) from JonSkeet himself might be useful too, but summarazing, it is a feature that is not currently supported in *Expression Trees* (like the one you are passing as parameter to the `MapFrom` method).

Hope it helps